# How to display inline several <li> with 100% width when browser size changes?

Tags: css

I want to display li element with 100% of the viewport size.
I found the solution from [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434270/how-to-display-inline-several-li-with-100-width), however it is not sufficient with my need, that is, I also want li element stay with 100% width **even though browser size changes**.
Is it possible using only pure css? or do I need to use additional javascript code?
Thanks.

Comment: surely `width: 100%;` is adequate unless I have mis-understood the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the other post in a fiddle to check, and it is working fine for me, are you sure you use all the correct parameters ?

```
div {overflow:auto;width:100%;}
ul {margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;}
li {width:100%;display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PDVEM/1/

Edit : To answer your comment, i'm not sure it is possible to synchronize scrollbar position and window size with pure css (maybe using some text-align:center; tricks), but IT IS possible with javascript :

```
//store the current scroll value
div.scroll(function(){
    currentScrollPos = div.scrollLeft();
    currentLi = (currentScrollPos/divWidth);
})

//on resize re-positions the scrollbar        
$(window).resize(function(){
     divWidth = parseInt(div.css('width'));
     newScrollPos = currentLi*divWidth;
     div.scrollLeft(newScrollPos);
})
```

See this fiddle for full example :

http://jsfiddle.net/PDVEM/3/

Comment: Thanks jonBreizh, I already tried this method, but my requirement is little bit diferrent. Let't say I am looking at second li element then resize the browser, you will see first li element with second li element because horizontal scroll position is not changed. I still want to see only second li element even though browser is resized

Comment: Check my answer, I edited the fiddle to do exactly as you wished. Hope this helps